# Ionic 4 sub array undefined while index is correct

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I've try to use console.log to view the value, but noticeSet2[index] value is undefined. And when I print noticeSet, it will show all the data in the array. And I've try to print the index at console.log, and it show the index that match the array.

I try to create a sub menu in the sub menu of a main menu which is noticeSet and the main menu work just fine. I try the similar method and it doesn't work. all I need to solve now is to show the noticeSet2[index] value. Thanks

```
toggleItem(index, item) {

    //this.noticeSet2[index].open = !this.noticeSet2[index].open;

    console.log("here");
    console.log(this.noticeSet2[0]);
    console.log(this.noticeSet2[index]);
    console.log(index);

    let obj = {resident_id: this.resident_id,id: item.id}

    this.authService.postData(obj, "getSubCategoryList").then((result) =>{
      this.responseData = result;
        if(this.responseData.feedData){
          //this.noticeSet2[item.id] = this.responseData.feedData;
          this.noticeSet3[this.noticeSet2[item.id]] = this.responseData.feedData;
          this.isDataAvailable = true;
        //console.log(this.noticeSet);
        }
      }, (err) => {
      });
  }



<ion-list *ngFor="let item of noticeSet; let i = index;" lines="none"  class="accordion-list" detail="false"
    no-padding >

    <button ion-item tappble style="font-weight:bold;color:#424242;" (click)="getSubCategoryList(i,item)" [ngClass]="{'section-active':item.open,'section':!item.open}">
      <ion-icon item-right slot="end" name="arrow-forward" *ngIf="!item.open"
        style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon item-right slot="end" name="arrow-down" *ngIf="item.open"
        style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;color:rgb(74, 137, 220)"></ion-icon>
      {{ item.title }}
    </button>


    <div *ngIf="noticeSet2[item.id] && item.open">
      <ion-list *ngFor="let item of noticeSet2[item.id]; let j = index;" lines="none" class="child-list">
        <button ion-item  (click)="toggleItem(j,item)" *ngIf="item.title"
          [ngClass]="{'child-active':item.open, 'child':!item.open}">
          <ion-icon item-left slot="start" name="add" *ngIf="!item.open" style="font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold;">
          </ion-icon>
          <ion-icon item-left slot="start" name="close" *ngIf="item.open" style="font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold;">
          </ion-icon>
          <ion-label>
            {{ item.title }}
          </ion-label>
        </button>

        <div *ngIf="noticeSet3[this.noticeSet2[item.id]] && item.open">
         <ion-list  *ngFor="let item of noticeSet3[this.noticeSet2[item.id]]" class="child-list-list" lines="none">
          <ion-item class="child-item" *ngIf="item.title">
            <button ion-item >
              {{item.title}}
            </button>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </div>

      </ion-list>
    </div>
  </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use value inside the promise. 
You have two ways to proceed:

First one is to use

> .then( **function()** => { [...] }

instead of

> .then((result) => { [...] }

it will works.

The Second one is to use special variable NOT inside your {}.

```
    var that = this;
// ...
.then(function() { that.variable })
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried but it doesn't work =3=